Repository beans are not found after upgrade to Springboot 3.2.1 and java 21
I upgraded a project from Java 11 and Spring boot 2.4.5 to Java 21 and Spring boot 3.2.1. After the upgrade interfaces that extend CrudRepository are not found as beans. The project fails to start during the initialization
The error I get is A component required a bean of type 'com.zoominfo.dozi.passivelogin.repo.CompanyRepo' that could not be found
Dependencies are:
dependencies {
    implementation 'net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:7.3'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.15.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.15.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.15.0'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'

    implementation 'com.google.cloud.sql:mysql-socket-factory:1.6.2'
    implementation 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.onelogin:java-saml-core:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.onelogin:java-saml:2.9.0'


    implementation 'com.auth0:java-jwt:3.18.2'

    implementation 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.15'

    implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-core:10.11'
    implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-httpclient:10.11'
    implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-jackson:10.11'
    implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-slf4j:10.11'

    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.5.0'

    implementation 'redis.clients:jedis:3.2.0'

    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre'
    implementation 'com.github.michaelgantman:MgntUtils:1.7.0.1'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.22'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test:3.3.9.RELEASE'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.6.28'
    testImplementation 'com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-standalone:3.0.1'

    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
}

Spring boot version:
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.1'
    id 'java'
}


And the error is? Your dependencies are? Generally this comes from trying to outsmart the dependency management done by Spring Boot Starters and including incompatible dependencies and/or providing configuration where auto-configuration is preferred.

@M.Deinum - I updated the question. But in general all the configs remain the same except the version related dependencies

Please don't include snippets, include all your dependencies and version overrides you might have.

@M.Deinum - updated

Dependencies seem to be fine. You also followed this with regards to updating? I also doubt that this is the only part of the stacktrace. Can you enable debug logging and share the logs?

In my case I forgot to replace javax.persistence. prefix with jakarta.persistence. in all the imports. That solved my problem

Which is what I suspected but that isn't clear from your dependencies, so you have some other dependency pulling in incompatible modules.

@M.Deinum Thanks for your help
